# Why does the httpJSON method in Network.Http.Simple throw an exception?

Tags: json, api, haskell

Here is the code I am running:

```
makeRequest = do
    response <- httpJSON "GET http://httpbin.org/get" :: IO (Response ())
    putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
```

It uses the httpJSON method from [Network.Http.Simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.2.3.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html)

If I navigate to the URL http://httpbin.org/get I can see that the JSON returned is valid.

However, the code returns the following error:

```
Exception: JSONConversionException Request {
  host                 = "httpbin.org"
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json")]
  path                 = "/get"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 200, statusMessage = "OK"}, responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("Connection","keep-alive"),("Server","meinheld/0.6.1"),("Date","Wed, 01 Nov 2017 15:41:54 GMT"),("Content-Type","application/json"),("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true"),("X-Powered-By","Flask"),("X-Processed-Time","0.000639915466309"),("Content-Length","226"),("Via","1.1 vegur")], responseBody = Object (fromList [("origin",String "87.194.144.188"),("args",Object (fromList [])),("url",String "http://httpbin.org/get"),("headers",Object (fromList [("Accept",String "application/json"),("Accept-Encoding",String "gzip"),("Connection",String "close"),("Host",String "httpbin.org")]))]), responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose}) "expected (), encountered Object"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Because you specify the type of `IO (Response ())`, `httpJSON` will try to parse the response body using the `FromJSON` instance of `()`. You could try replacing `()` with `Value` - I think that will parse arbitrary JSON.